# Integration trig substitution $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 + 16}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 + 16}}$$

With some magic I get down to $$\frac{1}{4} \int\frac{1}{\sin\theta} d\theta$$

Now is where I am lost. How do I do this? I tried integration by parts but it doesn't work.

Comment: [See this](http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/csc.htm).

Comment: I wonder how you got to $\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta}$. The obvious substitution I see leads to $\frac{dt}{\cosh t}$.

Comment: How is a hyperbolic subsitution ever obvious? Lol

Comment: @julien $\sec \theta$ was $1/\cos \theta$?

Comment: I got to it fromt trig sub on the inside making it sec^2/tansec^2 making it sec/tan or 1/sin.

Comment: @Dantheman Because those are what you get from $\sqrt{x^2 - c}$ naturally.

Comment: The question I have is how much of integral calculus does one need to develop every time.  Having reduced the integrand to $\csc{\theta}$, can you just pull out a short Table of Indefinite Integrals and read it off?

Comment: I don't have all the hyperbolic identites memorized.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, another standard way of dealing with that is the trig $x=4\sec\theta$ which yields $\int \frac{4\sec\theta \tan\theta d\theta }{4\sec\theta 4\tan\theta }=\int \frac{d\theta}{4}=\frac{\mbox{arcsec} (x/4)}{4}+C$. If it really is $-16$, the OP made a mistake. If is $+16$, then $x=4\tan\theta$ yields cosec indeed.

Comment: $1/\sin \theta$ is $\csc \theta$.  It is a good idea to have the integral of $\sec \theta$, which is $\ln|\sec \theta + \tan \theta| + C$, in your mathematical toolbelt.  Once you have that, the integral of $\csc \theta$ is very similar: $-\ln|\csc \theta + \cot \theta| + C$

Comment: There is just so much to memorize I don't know how to go about it, just for this section I need to have commited to memory about 40 or so identities and I have so little time to learn it all.

Comment: What was the *magic* substitution from $$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-16}} $$ to $$\frac{1}{4} \int\frac{1}{\sin\theta}
 d\theta\ ?$$

Comment: $u = z^2 +16$  $du  = 2xdx$  $$\int \frac {sec^2 \theta d\theta}{tan\theta d\theta}$$  $$\int sec\theta/tan\theta$$  $$\int 1/sin$$

Comment: So your first integral is not $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-16}}$ but $\int 
\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+16}}$, because

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+16}},\qquad x=\tan \theta ,dx=\sec
^{2}\theta d\theta  \\
&=&\int \frac{\sec ^{2}\theta }{\left( \tan \theta \right) 4\sec \theta }
\,d\theta =\int \frac{\sec \theta }{4\tan \theta }\,d\theta  \\
&=&\int \frac{\sec \theta }{4\tan \theta }\,d\theta =\int \frac{1}{4\sin
\theta }\,d\theta.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: It was a typo, + is correct.

Comment: @Dantheman Thanks!

Comment: This problem can be done without a trigonometric substitution.  See my answer below.  The hardest integrals that can be done by elementary methods are those of $d\theta/\cos\theta$ and $d\theta/\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta}=\int\csc\theta d\theta=\int\frac{\csc\theta(\csc\theta+\cot\theta)}{\csc\theta+\cot\theta}d\theta$$

Now what’s the derivative of that last denominator?

Comment: You seemed to have massively complicated things. Also I see what you did but how would I never to do that?

Comment: @Dantheman Not really. That is the standard workaround such integral.

Comment: @Dantheman: It’s a standard formula and a standard derivation of it. I find it a little easier to remember the idea behind the derivation than to remember the antiderivative itself, especially since a very similar trick takes care of $\int\sec\theta d\theta$. For these two integrals you have to remember **something**, and I prefer ideas to formulas.

Comment: So I need to memorize that to find the integral of sec and cot I need to know to multiply by its derivative over its derivative? So I need to memorize 2 more derivatives and that the method to get these integrals is that?

Comment: Also is scs + cot useful? It isn't a derivative of anything.

Comment: @Dantheman: You could simply memorize the antiderivatives of the secant and cosecant; I find it easier to remember how to derive them from things that I already know, in this case $\int\frac{du}u$ and the derivatives of the secant, tangent, cosecant, and cotangent.

Comment: @Dantheman: Do you mean $\csc\theta+\cot\theta$? It’s useful right here, in finding the antiderivative of $\csc\theta$. The fact that it’s not the derivative of anything very simple is completely irrelevant, since I’m not taking its antiderivative.

Comment: I don't see what to do next.

Comment: @Dantheman: What is the derivative of the denominator? How does that derivative compare with the numerator? (And I mentioned $\int\frac{du}u$ in the other comment for a reason.)

Comment: Why does the derivative of the denominator matter? I don't understand.

Comment: -cscxcotx -csc^2x

Comment: @Dantheman: Right; and how does that compare with the numerator of the fraction?

Comment: Seems to be off by a factor of -csc

Comment: @Dantheman: No, it’s simply the negative of the numerator. If you let $u$ be the denominator, the integral is $\int\frac{-du}u$, which is easy to compute.

Comment: Just tell me what to do I am lost.

Comment: @Dantheman: I just did: make the $u$-substitution $u=\csc\theta+\cot\theta$. When you carry it out, you get $\int\frac{-du}u=-\int\frac{du}u$. That last integral is one that you definitely should know: $-\int\frac{du}u=-\ln|u|+C$. Now substitute back to get rid of $u$.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE 2 The first integral is not $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-16}}$ but $\int 
\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+16}}$ (as noticed by  julien), because

\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+16}},\qquad x=\tan \theta ,dx=\sec
^{2}\theta d\theta  \\
&=&\int \frac{\sec ^{2}\theta }{\left( \tan \theta \right) 4\sec \theta }%
\,d\theta =\int \frac{\sec \theta }{4\tan \theta }\,d\theta  \\
&=&\int \frac{\sec \theta }{4\tan \theta }\,d\theta =\int \frac{1}{4\sin
\theta }\,d\theta \text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}

---

Use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) $$t=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

Then

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin \theta }\,d\theta =\int \frac{2}{\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}
\left( 1+t^{2}\right) }\,dt=\int \frac{1}{t}\,dt=\ln \left\vert t\right\vert
+C=\ln \left\vert \tan \frac{\theta }{2}\right\vert +C.$$

**Comment**: The Weierstrass substitution is a *universal standard substitution* to evaluate an integral of a rational fraction in $\sin \theta,\cos \theta$, i.e. a rational fraction of the form

$$R(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)=\frac{P(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)}{Q(\sin \theta,\cos \theta)},$$

where $P,Q$  are polynomials in $\sin \theta,\cos \theta$

$$
\begin{equation*}
\tan \frac{\theta }{2}=t,\qquad\theta =2\arctan t,\qquad d\theta =\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}dt
\end{equation*},
$$

which converts the integrand into a rational function in $t$. We know from trigonometry that

$$\cos \theta =\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{
\theta}{2}}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\qquad \sin \theta =\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}
\frac{\theta }{2}}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$

*Proof*. A possible proof is the following one, which uses the double-angle formulas and the identity $\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}+\sin ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}=1$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \theta &=&\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}=\frac{\frac{\cos ^{2}
\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}}{\frac{\cos ^{2}
\frac{\theta}{2}+\sin ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}}=\frac{1-\tan ^{2}
\frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}, \\
&& \\
\sin \theta &=&2\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\cos \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{\frac{2\sin \frac{\theta}{2}
\cos \frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}}{\frac{\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}+\sin ^{2}
\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{\theta}{2}}}=\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}
\frac{\theta}{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

---

Another possible substitution is the [Euler substitution](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions)
$$
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{x^{2}+16}=t+x.
\end{equation*}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^{2}+16}}=\int \frac{2}{t^{2}-16}\,dt \\
&=&\int \frac{1}{4\left( t-4\right) }-\frac{1}{4\left( t+4\right) }dt=\frac{1
}{4}\ln \left\vert \frac{t-4}{t+4}\right\vert +C \\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\ln \left\vert \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x-4}{\sqrt{x^{2}+16}-x+4}
\right\vert +C.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: Well that is disheartening. More stuff to memorize?

Comment: @Dantheman You insist on memorizing. Try learning instead. Comprehending what's going it. It will benefit you the most.

Comment: So more stuff to learn? I already don't have enough time to learn what we do in class, how could I possibly learn a whole new method?

Comment: @Dantheman No, this substitution is a universal substitution for a rational function in $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$. Sometimes there are faster methods but this substitution is worth knowing. It allows you to reduce the integral to one of a rational function in $t$.

Comment: @Dantheman The suggestion in this answer is the best so far. It is not necessarily efficient, but it is a method that allows you, not only solve this problem, but also solve any problem of the form $\int R(\sin(x),\cos(x))dx$ for $R$ rational.

Comment: Oh well I have not seen it in class and it does not seem easy to learn so I doubt it will be on the test.  Ican really only afford to spend time on test material.

Comment: Believe me when I say this. The test material has been stupidly designed. Learn this method and you will be among the top students in integration. This method allows you to tackle **any** of the trigonometric integrals they will give you. In addition, the original integral can be solved by a substitution that is not trigonometric called Euler's substitutions. I will add an answer talking a little about it. They allow you to solve  almost **any** of the integrals with radicals they will give you.

Comment: Hah, I will never be a top student in any math class. I am most likeyl going to fail this class. This is do or die, I don't have time to mess around with these other things that won't be on the test.

Comment: @Dantheman Notice something. This is called Weierstrass substitution, the one I will tell you about is called Euler's substitutions. Weierstrass and Euler are two of the greatest mathematicians ever. You can be sure the substitutions that carry their names are really the powerful tools. Most integrals you are given in class becomes really stupid exercises when you know the right way to deal with them. That trigonometric substitution is the bad teaching.It is the reason some students seem to be not good for math. What is really not good for math is the course material that you have been given

Comment: Another thing that should tell you this is the right way to study is that this is a method that is not only solving this problem for you, it is method that will solve **any** other similar problem they will throw at you. Those trigonometric substitutions they suggest in school break down more often than they solve problems. It is only for very specific exercises that they are useful, exercises that were finely designed to work with trigonometric substitutions.

Comment: @Dantheman If the deduction of the trigonometric formulas I made above is not intuitive for you, see the geometric interpretation in the Wikipedia page I linked to.

Comment: @Franklin.vp I think we got your point. E and W are indeed a good systematic treatment and that's how I was taught, so I would also defend it. But maybe it is not necessary to insult the majority of the north american teachers who go through trigonometric substitution. Unfortunately or not, that's what the OP will be expected to do on integrals that actually work nicely like that.

Comment: @julien I stand by what I said. I have even told James Stewart about it in person (although he probably forgot or ignored it). All integrals used in basic calculus courses fall in no more than 10 classes that can be solved without thinking. It is dishonest to know that not to teach students. Teachers either: 1-Don't know about it. 2-Are just following a program they were told to follow. 3-Choose it just because it is easier for them. I have followed a program I do not agree with. Sometimes you can only suggest to your superior things can be different and hope for them to do something.

Comment: @Franklin.vp It seems that most of the north american calculus textbooks originate from the same matrix. I was once told it was anterior to Stewart. But surely the fact that Stewart's text is so massively used has a deep influence by itself. I had never seen these trig sub before teaching in the US. I only knew W. But I just did like everybody else. I'd be curious to know how integral calculus will be taught in 50 years...

Comment: @julien I think indefinite integration will take the same route as arithmetic. The manual skills will fade. This is not a bad thing, really. It is not so important to be able to do by hand integrals of really hard rational functions, as it is not so important to compute 16th roots by hand or multiply large numbers. The algorithm to compute radicals by hand was already not taught in my time. Yet at least we teach the general method for multiplying numbers in decimal notation, and not only the shortcut tricks to multiply 2-digit numbers. I hope with indefinite integration will happen the same.

Comment: @Franklin.vp Yeah, that's a possibility. It would be interesting to have Ron Gordon's take on that.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta
&=\int\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sin^2(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-\int\frac1{1-\cos^2(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
&=-\frac12\int\left(\frac1{1-\cos(\theta)}+\frac1{1+\cos(\theta)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is dcos? I domt follow

Comment: @Dantheman: $\mathrm{d}\cos(\theta)=-\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$. You can think of this as the substitution $u=\cos(\theta)$ and then $$\int\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta =-\frac12\int\left(\frac1{1-u} + \frac1{1+u}\right) \,\mathrm{d}u$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer to the integral of the trigonometric function is the one given by *Americo Tavares*. Now, the original integral can be treated directly without the unnecessary trigonometric substitution.

Often forgotten in current Calculus textbooks. Are the [Euler's substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) that allow you to solve not only that integral but **every one** of the form $\int R(\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c},x)\text{d}x$, where $R(x,y)$ is any [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).

These substitutions transform your integral (and any of the form above) into the integral of a rational function. From there the problem is solved because we know [how to compute integrals of any rational function](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nironi/primitives-of-ratio.pdf).

PS: The algorithm I linked for computing integrals of rational functions is not the only one. There are many others.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if another method works:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+16}} = \int\frac{x\,dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+16}} = \int \frac{du/2}{(u-16)\sqrt{u}}
$$
where $u=x^2+16$ so that $du=2x\,dx$.  Now let $w=\sqrt{u}$ so that $w^2=u$ and $2w\,dw=du$.  Then we have
$$
\int\frac{w\,dw}{(w^2-16)w} = \int\frac{dw}{(w-4)(w+4)} =\int\left(\frac{\bullet}{w-4} + \frac{\bullet}{w+4}\right) \, dw,\quad\text{ etc.}
$$

Conclusion: **It can be done without a trigonometric substitution.**

Comment: That seems much easier, trig is like magic to me and I don't have all the indentities memorized. I just fear that the test will be full of trick questions.

Comment: @Dantheman : Glad you liked it.  Trigonometric substitutions aren't really trick questions, but you do need to know some things to use them.