# Evaluation of $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}$

Tags: calculus

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}$$

$x = 3\sec\theta$

$dx = 3\tan\theta \sec\theta\,d\theta$

$$\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{3\tan\theta\sec\theta}{\sqrt{\sec^2 + 1}} d\theta$$

$$ \int \sec\theta d\theta$$

I have no idea how to continue without looking up tables which I cannot do on a test, how would I proceed or have I already gone wrong?

Comment: Try a similar trick to the one used in [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/434842/55235).

Comment: I am not clever enough to make that work. What is the goal?

Comment: Stop the self deprecating comments. Mathematics beats down EVERYONE. The goal is the same as in the link I posted above. Did you understand what happened in the other question?

Comment: Not entirely, I don't see the goal of putting in what seems to be random trig fucntions.

Comment: I added more stuff to my answer.

Comment: You have $\sec^2\theta+1$ where you need $\sec^2\theta-1$, which is the same as $\tan^2\theta$.

Comment: Three answers so far, but I'm the only one whose's up-voted the question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Good point. I see that happen a lot. I forgot. Upvoted now.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Multiply $\sec$ by $\displaystyle 1=\frac{\sec(\theta)+\tan (\theta)}{\sec (\theta)+\tan (\theta)}$.

**Further hint:** $\displaystyle \int \sec (\theta) d\theta=\int \sec (\theta) \cdot 1\,d\theta=\int \sec (\theta) \frac{\sec(\theta)+\tan (\theta)}{\sec (\theta)+\tan (\theta)}d\theta=\int \frac{(\sec(\theta))^2+\sec (\theta)\tan (\theta)}{\sec (\theta)+\tan (\theta)}d\theta$.

Now differentiating $\theta \mapsto \sec (\theta) + \tan (\theta)$, you can find $\displaystyle \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sec (\theta) + \tan (\theta)\right)=(\sec(\theta))^2+\sec (\theta)\tan (\theta)$.

Finally use $\displaystyle \int \frac{u'}{u}=\log (|u|).$

Comment: That doesn't seem right, how do I differentiate that?

Comment: @Dantheman I added more stuff to my answer. I gotta run. Hopefully someone else will assist you if you need it. Otherwise I'll check back in a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

Another method:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \int\sec\theta\mathrm{d}\theta&=&\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos^2\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin\theta}{(1-\sin\theta)(1+\sin\theta)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\left(\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin\theta}{1-\sin\theta}+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta}\right)=\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: This method is the most straightforward one posted so far.

Comment: Where does the first sin come from?

Comment: @Dantheman $\mathrm{d}\sin\theta=\cos\theta\mathrm{d}\theta$

Comment: What is d? I domt follow

Comment: @Dantheman Consider $\sin (\theta)$. Differentiate it: $\displaystyle \frac{d\sin (\theta)}{d\theta}=\cos (\theta)$. Now the wrong part comes, (but it works). 'Multiply' by $d\theta$ to get $d\sin (\theta)=\cos (\theta)d\theta$. It does not only work in this case, it works with integrals in general. It is formally wrong, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you the work with Euler's substitutions so you see that you don't need to come up with any imaginative trick.

First the [Euler's substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#The_first_substitution_of_Euler_a_.3E_0) tells you to introduce a new variable $t$ such that $\sqrt{x^2-9}=x+t$. From this we get that $x^2-9=x^2+2xt+t^2$, i.e. $$x=\frac{-9-t^2}{2t}$$ and $$\sqrt{x^2-9}=\frac{-9-t^2}{2t}+t$$

Then, differentiating you get $$dx=\left(\frac{9}{2t^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\text{d}t$$.

Putting these in the integral we get

$$\int \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\int\frac{2t}{-9+t^2}\frac{9-t^2}{2t^2}\text{d}t.$$

Now simplify a little to get $$\int\frac{-\text{d}t}{t}=-\ln(t).$$

Returning now to the old variable $x$, using that $t=\sqrt{x^2-9}-x$ we get

$$\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=-\ln(\sqrt{x^2-9}-x)+constant.$$

If you want you can also rewrite this in the equivalent form: $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-9}-x}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}+x}{-9}\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2-9}+x\right)+constant.$$

I am telling you, **those trigonometric substitutions are an educational nonsense**. The only thing we had to do here was to notice that this was an integral of the form $R(\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c},x)$, for $R$ rational, and to remember what is the Euler substitution corresponding to it (there are only $3$ of them). The rest is just mindless computation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just for fun, here's a substitution that works:
$$
w = \tan\left(\frac\theta2+\frac\pi4\right)
$$
If you're good at trigonometric identities, you can then derive these:
$$
\sec\theta = \frac{1+w^2}{2w}, \qquad d\theta=\frac{2\,dw}{1+w^2}.
$$
Then you have
$$
\int\sec\theta\,d\theta = \int \frac{dw}{w} = \cdots\cdots
$$
(I have a short note in the current *Monthly* about this.  Also see [the Wikipedia article about this integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function), which I created a couple of years ago.  You'll see a link to a paper about its application to cartography, that being the reason why people first wanted to know how to do this integral.  This particular substitution is not (yet?) in the Wikipedia article.)

(What I privately think of as **the cartographer's tangent half-angle formula** says $\tan\left(\dfrac\theta2+\dfrac\pi4\right)=\sec\theta+\tan\theta$.  But maybe someone else has called it that?)